# Pandas histogram 'by' parameter in spyder

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to produce some histograms from a dataframe of data fro url and have them grouped by the dataframe columns. tried 'by =' [below], but when run in Spyder it runs through and when it goes to draw the histograms it appears to draw data on top of each other ['spyder' image below]. guessing this is because of an incorrect use of 'by ='?

[clearly, new to python and pandas]

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'

weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

df = pd.read_csv(weburl, names=['sepal length in cm', 'sepal width in cm', 'petal length in cm', 'petal width in cm', 'class'])

columnsNames = ['sepal length in cm', 'sepal width in cm', 'petal length in cm', 'petal width in cm']

def prodHisto(integers):

    mylist = list(integers)

    for i in mylist:
        x = df.hist(by = columnsNames, bins = i, column = columnsNames)
    return x

print(prodHisto([5,15,30]))
```

[spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0xFU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better not use a function to generate a plot and then *print* the histograms you obtained for all the different values of bins you want to try. You'll definitely obtain a mess.

The function *hist()* plots the result by itself, so don't assign it to a variable (plot successively the histogram for *i=5,15,30*).

To visualize the distribution of your features do as follows :

--> without using **by**

```
bin_list = [5,15,30]

for i in bin_list:
    plt.figure() #Creates a new figure
    for j, chan in enumerate(df.columns):
        plt.subplot(221 + j)
        df[chan].hist(bins=i)
        plt.title("%s" %chan)
```

--> using **by**

```
bin_list = [5,15,30]

for i in bin_list:
    plt.figure() #Creates a new figure
    df.hist(by=df.columns, bins=i)
```

Comment: Specifically trying the "using by "suggestion", I get the following error: "AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length". From what I found about this error it seems to happen when trying to group by an empty list? But as far as I'm tracking, the grouper here is "columns" and that's clearly not empty.